# SharePoint 2016 : Exclude people in search result

Tags: search, search-results, people-search

We have a requirement wherein on the search result page people (users) should not be shown.

Kindly let know how this can be achieved.

Googled for it however finding posts to exclude inactive users but not getting any post to exclude all users

Kindly let know if any further details required.

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you are in the Enterprise Search Center, do you want to remove the People Vertical (the tab) and the Page? Note that this will NOT prevent searching for people, it just makes it harder. Would you rather NOT have ANY people results in your Search Index?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the results web-part on the results page and try to change the query. You are able to exclude certain objects from the results, such as users.

Comment: Hi Toine, Thank you for the response. I tried to look around how to exclude users but not able to figure out. Apologies for these silly questions. I am pretty new to SharePoint search. Could you please elaborate a bit

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the default Result Source doesn't bring back people result without implementation, so I assume you don't want to show the "People" tab.

To achieve that, you can go to the:

```
 Site Setting > Search Setting
```

That way you can remove the People tab along with the page.

In this link below, author is adding another vertical/tab. You can see the section she added a link is where you want to remove the "People" vertical/tab.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/12/how-to-add-a-custom-search-vertical-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Hi YogaPanda, thank you for your response. I tried to look for people option in search settings however not able to get one. Could you please share a link or steps to do this.. apologies for my basic questions

Comment: @shoab Hi I have updated the answer, let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

See this post, maybe it helps:
https://www.rlvision.com/blog/excluding-external-users-from-search-results-in-sharepoint-online/#comment-15241

You can modify the result source or only the search result query in e.g. a webpart by adding to the query -property:"value" (see, that there is a '-' prefixed before the property name to exclude results with this value of this property from the search results. The '-'-prefix means 'not'.)